# Why does my feature support test not run before syntax error occurs?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm doing Javascript feature support testing on my site, but I'm running into an issue while testing on IE11 that is causing a syntax error (because of a default parameter) prior to executing my feature test.

My application builds a script tag to inject into the layout view. That script tag is built using a configuration that defines all of the JS dependencies. I've ensured that the resulting JS file that's delivered to the browser has my feature detection at the top of the combined script (right after jQuery). But what seems to be happening is that some function that's defined later on in the script is running (or parsed?) prior to running my feature detection expression.

For more clarity, this is an example of what my script tag looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/jscript?load=feature-detection,global,login&version=1820523616"></script>
```

Which results in a script file that first contains jQuery, then my feature-detection.js, then everything else. This is the line in one of the JS files after feature detection that causes the syntax error:

```
processMessages: function(problem, container, useMessage = true) {...}
```

EDIT:

To be clear, I'm unsure why the syntax error would occur before the feature detection logic, even though my feature detection occurs far earlier in the code. This is what my combined script looks like:

```
/* jQuery v3.2.0 ... */
// This is a placeholder for jQuery code

// Test browser support for 'for...of' statement.
// If this feature is lacking, ES6 support is lacking from the browser
try {
    eval("for (var i of []);");
} catch(ex) {
    // Show 'Unsupported Browser' banner
    alert('GET BETTER BROWSER');
}

// The rest of my JS files, which would contain several non-supported features
processMessages: function(problem, container, useMessage = true) {...}
```

The "alert" is never triggered in IE11, instead I get "Expected ')'" pointing to the default parameter function

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use default parameter values in JS like that, that's probably what's breaking in IE.

You'll have to default it like this instead:

```js
processMessages: function(problem, container, useMessage) {
  if (typeof useMessage === 'undefined') useMessage = true;
}
```

Comment: In modern browsers, [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) works. My question is really about why the syntax error would occur _before_ the feature detection logic, even though my feature detection occurs far earlier in the code.

Comment: Default parameters are an ES6 feature, which no version of IE supports. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. My problem isn't that IE doesn't support default parameters, it's that I'm unsure of the order in which the code is interpreted by the browser. I was under the impression that code that came _before_ a syntactical error (i.e. my feature detection logic that comes before the default parameters) would be executed first and handled accordingly.

Comment: So you are asking why you are getting syntax errors in IE yet you are using syntax that is invalid in IE only... I'm still going to recommend removing the invalid syntax and see if that resolves your issues.  JS doesn't work the way you are thinking, if the file contains invalid syntax that can't be parsed, it's not like it's just going to run the "good parts" only.

Comment: I expect the syntax error, I just thought that the file was interpreted (and executed) in order. My "feature detection" Javascript is used to trigger the display of an unsupported browser banner. I thought that my feature detection logic would run _before_ the syntax error was reported.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is first compiled then executed, it's a multistage process.

Your syntax error will occur at compilation cycle(or interpret time) which is why you are seeing it before your feature detection executes.

I am not a deep js expert so my terminology might be wrong but that's the idea behind your issue